# Wireless on laptop problem to connect

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I have 3 laptops, and I connect to internet via a wireless router. This router has some type of special connection, as there are several routers in the building that I believe all are connected to some type of internet server. (It's free internet in the building)

Situation is as follows:

```
pc 1: Connects with static IP, works OK.
pc 2: Connects with dynamic IP, works OK. 
pc 3: Can not connect with dynamic IP.
```

I can't see why pc3 doesn't work. However I see it has in the Wireless Network properties, something called AEGIS Protocol IEEE 802.1x...   Can this the problem? Can I uninstall it? This laptop is a Thinkpad T42.

All computers run XP Pro.

EDIT: 
Btw; I can ping between all computers without any problem..

Answer (score 0):

Attempt #1: Ensure that your credentials are typed in correctly. Double check this, because this is where most of the problems are nine times out of ten.

Attempt #2: Use some a good wireless network tool (such as Lenovo Internet Connection) and try to connect to the access point from that. (Mabey there is a problem with the user understanding Windows Wireless Management tool or there is a problem with the Windows Wireless Management tool)

Attempt #3 Right-click on My Network Places and go to properties. You should now see a screen that has items on it such as Wireless Network Connection, Local Area Connection, etc. Right click on the Wireless Network Connect, and click properties. Double click on Internet Protocol Version 4 or something among those line. It might also say TCP/IP v4. Make sure that both both of the options are set to automatically obtain.

Good Luck-

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm using the Hex key, and it must be correct. What does it mean though that I am able to ping between all computers, but still one of them does not go online?

Comment: I have never heard of that unless the computer doesn't know what the default gateway is. Also try making sure that you choose the correct data encryption (TKIP or AES). Try pinging Google.com

Comment: Very strange. Suddenly I could connect with a static IP.. And then a bit later, it doesn't work. I believe it must be something wrong with the server at the other side of the router. Just strange why I can connect one computer on dynamic IP and not this other one..

Comment: Also some times this laptop sees only one network, while my other two sees 3-4 networks. I wonder if the wireless card may be intermittently broken and need replacement..

Comment: You can get a wireless card on Newegg.com pretty cheap (especially in November). Try that and comment back if you try it.

Answer (score 0):

As something to check, but I'm hoping your systems are up to date.

Windows XP won't connect to a WPA2 type wireless until you've got all the updates. I'm sorry, but I don't know for certain if it's SP3 or just the various bazillion little updates, but I couldn't connect with the laptop until I installed SP3 using the 'distribution version' transferred with a flash drive.

And like David said, do check your passwords, credentials, WPA2 keys, DHCP settings, it really is often something that simple.

Comment: yea, it's a fresh XP Pro SP3 install, with all updates. Even reinstalled a couple of times the last days to try to fix this problem.. :|